# Error when enabling ArcGIS geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

We're trying to enable enterprise geodatabase functionality in an existing PostgreSQL database. We've already created the sde user (set as superuser) & sde schema.

We get the following error:

[image]

> "Could not create geodatabase tables and stored procedures. Failed to
>   execute (EnableEnterpriseGeodatabase).

the database is: "PostgreSQL 9.2.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

```
client: ArcGIS 10.2
```

Comment: Please always include errors as text so that they can be searched for in the future.

Comment: PG 9.2 was not supported until ArcGIS 10.2, but this error may be due to database name (only lowercase is allowed) or failure to name the SDE schema "sde". Please **edit** the question to include the input parameters to the CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase tool.

Comment: It's 10.2 (sorry, my mistake). it's sde (with lowercase). We didn't use CreateEnerpriseGeodatabse, because the database was already created. We used Enable Geodatabase.

Answer (score -1):

We had other schemas as well, and the sde user didn't have access to them, it had access only to the sde schema. In conclusion, the geodatabase administrator must have access to all the schemas that exist in the database.

Comment: This is not true. The 'sde' schema only needs access to the database which is being enabled. And you don't mention that ArcGIS10.1 installation in 9.2 not possible.

Comment: It's ArcGIS 10.2 (my mistake), and a PostgreSQL 9.2.9

Comment: Maybe it's a coincidence, but the moment we gave sde user access to the others schemas in the database, we got rid of the error and we succeeded in enabling the gdb.

Comment: Best practice is to use CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase at least once, so you get an idea of how it's expecting things.  I continue to use Create EGDB (vice *Enable* EGDB) even when the database exists and the sde login, user, and schema are all present (it skips those steps with warnings but not errors).  As it stands, this "solution" will not work for others.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Vince. I didn't know you could use Create EGDB on an existing geodatabase.

Comment: You can't, but you can use it on an existing **database**.